# Access a local file, but ensure it is up-to-date

Tags: python, caching

How can I use the Python standard library to get a file object, silently ensuring it's up-to-date from some other location?

A program I'm working on needs to access a set of files locally; they're
just normal files.

But those files are local cached copies of documents available at remote
URLs — each file has a canonical URL for that file's content.

(I write here about HTTP URLs, but I'm looking for a solution that isn't specific to any particular remote fetching protocol.)

I'd like an API for ‘get_file_from_cache’ that looks something like:

```python
file_urls = {
        "/path/to/foo.txt": "http://example.org/spam/",
        "other/path/bar.data": "https://example.net/beans/flonk.xml",
        }

for (filename, url) in file_urls.items():
    infile = get_file_from_cache(filename, canonical=url)
    do_stuff_with(infile.read())
```

- If the local file's modification timestamp is not significantly
  earlier than the `Last-Modified` timestamp for the document at the
  corresponding URL, `get_file_from_cache` just returns the file object
  without changing the file.
- The local file might be out of date (its modification timestamp may be
  significantly older than the `Last-Modified` timestamp from the
  corresponding URL). In that case, `get_file_from_cache` should first
  read the document's contents into the file, then return the file
  object.
- The local file may not yet exist. In that case, `get_file_from_cache`
  should first read the document content from the corresponding URL,
  create the local file, and then return the file object.
- The remote URL may not be available for some reason. In that case,
  `get_file_from_cache` should simply return the file object, or if that
  can't be done, raise an error.

So this is something similar to an HTTP object cache. Except where those
are usually URL-focussed with the local files a hidden implementation
detail, I want an **API that focusses on the local files, with the remote
requests a hidden implementation detail**.

Does anything like this exist in the Python library, or as simple code
using it? With or without the specifics of HTTP and URLs, is there some
generic caching recipe already **implemented with the standard library**?

This local file cache (ignoring the spcifics of URLs and network access)
seems like exactly the kind of thing that is **easy to get wrong** in
countless ways, and so should have a single obvious implementation
available.

Am I in luck? What do you advise?

Comment: Have a look at [ETag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag).

Comment: @User : That could work, if the sites that bignose wants to access do the right thing with their etags. OTOH, he doesn't mind if the cached version is a little bit out of date, and etags can't really help with that.

Answer (score 0):

From a quick Googling I couldn't find an existing library that can do, although I'd be surprised if there weren't such a thing. :)

Anyway, here's one way to do it using the popular Requests module. It'd be pretty easy to adapt this code to use urllib / urlib2, though.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

''' Download a file if it doesn't yet exist in offline cache, or if the online
    version is more than age seconds newer than the cached version.

    Example code for
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26436641/access-a-local-file-but-ensure-it-is-up-to-date

    Written by PM 2Ring 2014.10.18
'''

import sys
import os
import email.utils
import requests


cache_path = 'offline_cache'

#Translate local file names in cache_path to URLs
file_urls = {
    'example1.html': 'http://www.example.com/',
    'badfile': 'http://httpbin.org/status/404',
    'example2.html': 'http://www.example.org/index.html',
}


def get_headers(url):
    resp = requests.head(url)
    print "Status: %d" % resp.status_code
    resp.raise_for_status()
    for k,v in resp.headers.items():
        print '%-16s : %s' % (k, v)


def get_url_mtime(url):
    ''' Get last modified time of an online file from the headers
    and convert to a timestamp
    '''
    resp = requests.head(url)
    resp.raise_for_status()
    t = email.utils.parsedate_tz(resp.headers['last-modified'])
    return email.utils.mktime_tz(t)


def download(url, fname):
    ''' Download url to fname, setting mtime of file to match url '''
    print >>sys.stderr, "Downloading '%s' to '%s'" % (url, fname)
    resp = requests.get(url)
    #print "Status: %d" % resp.status_code
    resp.raise_for_status()

    t = email.utils.parsedate_tz(resp.headers['last-modified'])
    timestamp = email.utils.mktime_tz(t)
    #print 'last-modified', timestamp

    with open(fname, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(resp.content)
    os.utime(fname, (timestamp, timestamp))


def open_cached(basename, mode='r', age=0):
    ''' Open a cached file.

    Download it if it doesn't yet exist in cache, or if the online
    version is more than age seconds newer than the cached version.'''

    fname = os.path.join(cache_path, basename)
    url = file_urls[basename]
    #print fname, url

    if os.path.exists(fname):
        #Check if online version is sufficiently newer than offline version
        file_mtime = os.path.getmtime(fname)
        url_mtime = get_url_mtime(url)
        if url_mtime > age + file_mtime:
            download(url, fname)
    else:
        download(url, fname)

    return open(fname, mode)


def main():
    for fname in ('example1.html', 'badfile', 'example2.html'):
        print fname
        try:
            with open_cached(fname, 'r') as f:
                for i, line in enumerate(f, 1):
                    print "%3d: %s" % (i, line.rstrip())
        except requests.exceptions.HTTPError, e:
            print >>sys.stderr, "%s '%s' = '%s'" % (e, file_urls[fname], fname)
        print


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Of course, for real-world use you should add some proper error checking.

You may notice that I've defined a function `get_headers(url)` which never gets called; I used it during development & figured it might come in handy when expanding this program, so I left it in. :)